# Visual Studio Team Services with on premise Build server, Many unresolved denpendency errors

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, tfs-2015

Using Visual Studio Team Services, with an on premise build server on windows 2012r2.

Qeued build starts fine. Nugget restore seems to work fine.

However, when it gets to Build Solution step, I get a bunch of unresolved dependency errors (related to .net core framework) and build fails.
http://screencast.com/t/A1Btf9ygPY

Build agent is using a domain account to run as service.

I've installed following frameworks:
1.0.0-rc1-update1,  1.0.0-rc1-update2, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.6

Standard build definition, no extra steps:

project.json file of project to build
http://screencast.com/t/JAsjLdc4uL2

New to TFS 2015 and .net core.
So I hope I provided enough info?

Build File:

```
{
  "build": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "NuGet restore **\\*.sln",
      "task": {
        "id": "333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "solution": "**\\*.sln",
        "nugetConfigPath": "",
        "restoreMode": "restore",
        "noCache": "false",
        "nuGetRestoreArgs": "",
        "nuGetPath": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Build solution **\\*.sln",
      "task": {
        "id": "71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "solution": "**\\*.sln",
        "msbuildArgs": "",
        "platform": "$(BuildPlatform)",
        "configuration": "$(BuildConfiguration)",
        "clean": "false",
        "vsVersion": "14.0",
        "restoreNugetPackages": "false",
        "msbuildArchitecture": "x86",
        "logProjectEvents": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Test Assemblies **\\$(BuildConfiguration)\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
      "task": {
        "id": "ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "testAssembly": "**\\$(BuildConfiguration)\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
        "testFiltercriteria": "",
        "runSettingsFile": "",
        "overrideTestrunParameters": "",
        "codeCoverageEnabled": "false",
        "runInParallel": "false",
        "vsTestVersion": "14.0",
        "pathtoCustomTestAdapters": "",
        "otherConsoleOptions": "",
        "testRunTitle": "",
        "platform": "$(BuildPlatform)",
        "configuration": "$(BuildConfiguration)",
        "publishRunAttachments": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": true,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "Publish symbols path: ",
      "task": {
        "id": "0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "SymbolsPath": "",
        "SearchPattern": "**\\bin\\**\\*.pdb",
        "SymbolsFolder": "",
        "SkipIndexing": "false",
        "TreatNotIndexedAsWarning": "false",
        "SymbolsMaximumWaitTime": "",
        "SymbolsProduct": "",
        "SymbolsVersion": "",
        "SymbolsArtifactName": "Symbols_$(BuildConfiguration)"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": true,
      "displayName": "Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)",
      "task": {
        "id": "5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "SourceFolder": "$(build.sourcesdirectory)",
        "Contents": "**\\bin\\$(BuildConfiguration)\\**",
        "TargetFolder": "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)",
        "CleanTargetFolder": "false",
        "OverWrite": "false"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": true,
      "displayName": "Publish Artifact: drop",
      "task": {
        "id": "2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe",
        "versionSpec": "*"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "PathtoPublish": "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)",
        "ArtifactName": "drop",
        "ArtifactType": "Container",
        "TargetPath": "\\\\my\\share\\$(Build.DefinitionName)\\$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      }
    }
  ],
  "options": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "definition": {
        "id": "7c555368-ca64-4199-add6-9ebaf0b0137d"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "multipliers": "[\"BuildPlatform\",\"BuildConfiguration\"]",
        "parallel": "true",
        "continueOnError": "true",
        "additionalFields": "{}"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "definition": {
        "id": "a9db38f9-9fdc-478c-b0f9-464221e58316"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "workItemType": "309932",
        "assignToRequestor": "true",
        "additionalFields": "{}"
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "definition": {
        "id": "57578776-4c22-4526-aeb0-86b6da17ee9c"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "additionalFields": "{}"
      }
    }
  ],
  "triggers": [
    {
      "branchFilters": [
        "+master"
      ],
      "batchChanges": true,
      "maxConcurrentBuildsPerBranch": 1,
      "triggerType": 2
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "system.debug": {
      "value": "true",
      "allowOverride": true
    },
    "BuildConfiguration": {
      "value": "release",
      "allowOverride": true
    },
    "BuildPlatform": {
      "value": "any cpu",
      "allowOverride": true
    }
  },
  "retentionRules": [
    {
      "branches": [
        "+refs/heads/*"
      ],
      "artifacts": [],
      "artifactTypesToDelete": [
        "FilePath",
        "SymbolStore"
      ],
      "daysToKeep": 10,
      "minimumToKeep": 1,
      "deleteBuildRecord": true,
      "deleteTestResults": true
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://xentrina.visualstudio.com/c780efdf-5fcb-4a89-9b3b-343e3264a3e6/_apis/build/Definitions/1"
    },
    "web": {
      "href": "https://xentrina.visualstudio.com/_permalink/_build/index?collectionId=ddd3259f-c9ec-4c3a-898f-090aa57fe345&projectId=c780efdf-5fcb-4a89-9b3b-343e3264a3e6&definitionId=1"
    }
  },
  "buildNumberFormat": "1.0.$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)",
  "description": "CI for Xentrina",
  "jobAuthorizationScope": 2,
  "jobTimeoutInMinutes": 60,
  "repository": {
    "properties": {
      "connectedServiceId": "3de97bbc-74a0-4915-b919-72185a15552e",
      "apiUrl": "https://api.github.com/repos/XentrinaEnterpriseSolutions/Xentrina",
      "branchesUrl": "https://api.github.com/repos/XentrinaEnterpriseSolutions/Xentrina/branches",
      "cloneUrl": "https://github.com/XentrinaEnterpriseSolutions/Xentrina.git",
      "refsUrl": "https://api.github.com/repos/XentrinaEnterpriseSolutions/Xentrina/git/refs"
    },
    "id": "https://github.com/XentrinaEnterpriseSolutions/Xentrina.git",
    "type": "GitHub",
    "name": "XentrinaEnterpriseSolutions/Xentrina",
    "url": "https://github.com/XentrinaEnterpriseSolutions/Xentrina.git",
    "defaultBranch": "dev",
    "clean": "true",
    "checkoutSubmodules": false
  },
  "quality": 1,
  "authoredBy": {
    "id": "6ce0f3a7-5a7d-457a-9e37-e713ceffd5ff",
    "displayName": "Pablo Cazares",
    "uniqueName": "pablocazares@xentrina.com",
    "url": "https://xentrina.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities/6ce0f3a7-5a7d-457a-9e37-e713ceffd5ff",
    "imageUrl": "https://xentrina.visualstudio.com/_api/_common/identityImage?id=6ce0f3a7-5a7d-457a-9e37-e713ceffd5ff"
  },
  "queue": {
    "pool": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Default"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Default"
  },
  "path": "\\",
  "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Definition/1",
  "type": 2,
  "revision": 10,
  "createdDate": "2016-05-19T16:32:16.827Z",
  "id": 1,
  "name": "GitHub Xentrina",
  "url": "https://xentrina.visualstudio.com/c780efdf-5fcb-4a89-9b3b-343e3264a3e6/_apis/build/Definitions/1",
  "project": {
    "id": "c780efdf-5fcb-4a89-9b3b-343e3264a3e6",
    "name": "xentrina",
    "url": "https://xentrina.visualstudio.com/_apis/projects/c780efdf-5fcb-4a89-9b3b-343e3264a3e6",
    "state": "wellFormed",
    "revision": 63017861
  }
}
```

Build Sln file Output:

```
2016-05-19T17:01:23.0937842Z C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1'')) ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME, ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1'')) }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message -Verbose } ; $env:TF_BUILD = 'True' ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\Builds\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.28\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1' -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' ; $DebugPreference = 'Continue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create('. ''C:\Builds\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.28\VSBuild.ps1'''))"
2016-05-19T17:01:23.7344066Z ##[debug]VstsTaskSdk 0.6.2 commit b4160c33da0010bd83279e9ffa9bbf13bcbd1ce2
2016-05-19T17:01:23.7812777Z ##[debug]Entering C:\Builds\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.28\VSBuild.ps1.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.7969023Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\Builds\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.28\Task.json
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8125277Z ##[debug]Loaded 7 strings.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8125277Z ##[debug]Env:SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8125277Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\Builds\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.28\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8281521Z ##[debug]Loaded 7 strings.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8437768Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_VSVERSION: '14.0'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8437768Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_MSBUILDARCHITECTURE: 'x86'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8437768Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_MSBUILDARGS (empty)
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8437768Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_SOLUTION: 'C:\Builds\_work\2\s\**\*.sln'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8437768Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_PLATFORM: 'any cpu'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8594026Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_CONFIGURATION: 'release'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8594026Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_CLEAN: 'false'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8594026Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8594026Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_RESTORENUGETPACKAGES: 'false'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8594026Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8594026Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_LOGPROJECTEVENTS: 'true'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8594026Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: True
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8750270Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_VSLOCATION (empty)
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8750270Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_MSBUILDLOCATION (empty)
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8750270Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_MSBUILDVERSION (empty)
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8750270Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\Builds\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.28\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\MSBuildHelpers.psm1'.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8906522Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\Builds\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.28\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\module.json
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8906522Z ##[debug]Loaded 4 strings.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8906522Z ##[debug]Env:SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2016-05-19T17:01:23.8906522Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: C:\Builds\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.28\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2016-05-19T17:01:23.9062767Z ##[debug]Loaded 4 strings.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.9219011Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Format-MSBuildArguments'.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.9219011Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Invoke-BuildTools'.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.9219011Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Get-MSBuildPath'.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.9219011Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Get-SolutionFiles'.
2016-05-19T17:01:23.9219011Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Format-MSBuildArguments'.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.0937780Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Get-MSBuildPath'.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1094004Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Get-SolutionFiles'.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1094004Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Invoke-BuildTools'.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1094004Z ##[debug]Entering Get-SolutionFiles.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1250253Z ##[debug] Solution: 'C:\Builds\_work\2\s\**\*.sln'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1250253Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1250253Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: 'C:\Builds\_work\2\s\**\*.sln'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1718995Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1718995Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'C:\Builds\_work\2\s\**\*.sln'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1718995Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1718995Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'True'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1875255Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'False'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.1875255Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.4843992Z ##[debug]Path: C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln
2016-05-19T17:01:24.4843992Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.4843992Z ##[debug]Total found: 1
2016-05-19T17:01:24.4843992Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5000229Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-SolutionFiles.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5000229Z ##[debug]Entering Select-VSVersion.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5000229Z ##[debug] PreferredVersion: '14.0'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5000229Z ##[debug]Entering Get-VSPath.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5000229Z ##[debug] Version: '14.0'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5156479Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-VSPath.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5156479Z ##[debug]Leaving Select-VSVersion.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5156479Z ##[debug]Entering Select-MSBuildLocation.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5156479Z ##[debug] VSVersion: '14.0'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5156479Z ##[debug] Architecture: 'x86'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5312729Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MSBuildPath.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5312729Z ##[debug] Version: '14.0'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5312729Z ##[debug] Architecture: 'x86'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5937721Z ##[debug]MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5937721Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MSBuildPath.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.5937721Z ##[debug]Leaving Select-MSBuildLocation.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6093975Z ##[debug]Entering Format-MSBuildArguments.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6093975Z ##[debug] MSBuildArguments: ''
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6093975Z ##[debug] Platform: 'any cpu'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6093975Z ##[debug] Configuration: 'release'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6093975Z ##[debug] VSVersion: '14.0'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6093975Z ##[debug]Leaving Format-MSBuildArguments.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6250223Z ##[debug]Entering Invoke-BuildTools.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6250223Z ##[debug] NuGetRestore: 'False'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6250223Z ##[debug] SolutionFiles: 'C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6250223Z ##[debug] MSBuildLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6250223Z ##[debug] MSBuildArguments: ' /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6250223Z ##[debug] Clean: 'False'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6250223Z ##[debug] NoTimelineLogger: 'False'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6406468Z ##[debug]Entering Invoke-MSBuild.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6406468Z ##[debug] ProjectFile: 'C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6406468Z ##[debug] LogFile: 'C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln.log'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6406468Z ##[debug] MSBuildPath: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6406468Z ##[debug] AdditionalArguments: ' /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6406468Z ##[debug] NoTimelineLogger: 'False'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6562719Z ##[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6562719Z ##[debug]Env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY: 'C:\Builds'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.6562719Z ##[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\Builds\Agent\Worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.7031473Z ##[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.7031473Z ##[debug] FileName: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.7031473Z ##[debug] Arguments: '"C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln.log" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\Builds\Agent\Worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\Builds\Agent\Worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.7031473Z ##[debug] RequireExitCodeZero: 'True'
2016-05-19T17:01:24.7031473Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln.log" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\Builds\Agent\Worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\Builds\Agent\Worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
2016-05-19T17:01:24.7656464Z Build started 5/19/2016 10:01:24 AM.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z      1>Project "C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z      1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z        ValidateProjects:
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.Models" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.DataLayer" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.DomainClasses" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.WebApi" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.Repositories" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.UnitOfWork" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.Repositories.Test" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.UI.Test" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.8281459Z          The project "Xen.WebApi.Test" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9531452Z      1>Project "C:\Builds\_work\2\s\Xentrina.sln" (1) is building "C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\Xen.UI.xproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9531452Z      2>PrepareForBuild:
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9531452Z          Creating directory ".\bin\".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9843958Z          Creating directory ".\obj\Release\".
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9843958Z        PreComputeCompileTypeScript:
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9843958Z          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9843958Z        CompileTypeScript:
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9843958Z        Skipping target "CompileTypeScript" because it has no outputs.
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9843958Z        CoreCompile:
2016-05-19T17:01:24.9843958Z          C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina" --configuration Release --no-dependencies
2016-05-19T17:01:26.2656388Z          Project Xentrina (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected inputs are missing
2016-05-19T17:01:26.2656388Z          Compiling Xentrina for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
2016-05-19T17:01:34.0313113Z ##[error]src\Xentrina\project.json(41,46): Error NU1001: The dependency EntityFramework.Core >= 7.0.0-rc1-final could not be resolved.
2016-05-19T17:01:34.0469369Z      2>C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\project.json(41,46): error NU1001: The dependency EntityFramework.Core >= 7.0.0-rc1-final could not be resolved. [C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\Xen.UI.xproj]
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3125648Z ##[error]src\Xentrina\project.json(41,46): Error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved.
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3125648Z      2>C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\project.json(41,46): error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved. [C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\Xen.UI.xproj]
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z ##[error]src\Xentrina\project.json(11,78): Error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved.
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z      2>C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\project.json(11,78): error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved. [C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\Xen.UI.xproj]
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z ##[error]src\Xentrina\project.json(12,75): Error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved.
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z      2>C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\project.json(12,75): error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved. [C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\Xen.UI.xproj]
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z ##[error]src\Xentrina\project.json(22,66): Error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved.
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z      2>C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\project.json(22,66): error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved. [C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\Xen.UI.xproj]
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z ##[error]src\Xentrina\project.json(38,31): Error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved.
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z      2>C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\project.json(38,31): error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved. [C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\Xen.UI.xproj]
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z ##[error]src\Xentrina\project.json(21,65): Error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved.
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z      2>C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\project.json(21,65): error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved. [C:\Builds\_work\2\s\src\Xentrina\Xen.UI.xproj]
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z ##[error]src\Xentrina\project.json(30,57): Error NU1001: The dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5 could not be resolved.
2016-05-19T17:01:34.3281924Z
```

Comment: Hi Pcazar,  welcome to SO. Could you consider posting your build file and errors as text? its better for indexing.

Comment: It looks like you need to run a `dotnet` or `dnu` `restore` before you build.

Comment: Very nice!  That was it.  Thank you